# How to use struts taglib tag in JavaScript

Tags: java, struts

I am using a struts tag in my JS function i-e

```
var ptp = "<c:out value='${myFormBean.myVar[0]}'/>";
```

and it gives me the correct value by taking from appropriate bean, but i have to use it for multiple rows that are being showed there using a loop and that is why i send the index of row in the function, but when i try try to put that variable into the above line like

```
function myFucn(ind){
var ptp = "<c:out value='${myFormBean.myVar[ind]}'/>";// this does not show any thing
//OR
var ptp = "<c:out value='${myFormBean.myVar['+ind+']}'/>";//This beaks the HTML
//OR
var ptp = "<c:out value='${myFormBean.myVar["+ind+"]}'/>";//This beaks the HTML
}
```

Please help how to get the value from above tag using index as variable.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use this "<%='${myFormBean.myVar[ind]}'%>"; and see if it works

Comment: @Satya tried this but not working, same problem can you please suggest some other idea ??

Comment: What a loop are you talking about?

Comment: what do you see in page-source when this page gets rendered in the browser ? Can you please add that to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> JavaScript is a code running in the Client side, It will only be
>   functional when the Code is executed, I mean Called using a function
>   or Some.!! So i believe its not possible to get the values in the
>   JavaScript from the struts Tag..!!

The Possible way to do it is by Passing the values as arguments, you can pass the values 
using

```
myFucn(indValue,'<c:out value='${myFormBean.myVar[ind]}'/>','<c:out value='${myFormBean.myVar['+ind+']}'/>','<c:out value='${myFormBean.myVar["+ind+"]}'/>')
```

By this your function will receive this values in the Script function.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mixed the client-side code and server-side code. The "tag" is like you go shopping but there's no shopkeeper, you have to explicitly pick the one you want, not the way you ask for one item based on some criteria you provided.

If I understand your problem correctly, I would suggest create a function with ajax to retrieve desired data and set them on your HTML page.